# MappedInterceptor Bean Vs WebMvcConfigurer addInterceptors. What is the correct (modern) way for adding Spring HandlerInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I stumbled upon a configuration class for a project that was converted from legacy spring to Spring Boot. I see there are two ways interceptors are added. Like these

```
  @Configuration
  public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor( new MyInterceptorOne()).addPathPatterns("/api/data/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor mappedResponseHeaderInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(new String[] { "/static/css/**", "/static/img/**" }, new ResponseHeaderInterceptor());
    }
  }
```

both interceptors are working. I am wondering what is right way to add the interceptors in  Spring boot and why these two method exists

Comment: Both work, your first uses the `MappedInterceptor` internally. So more or less they are the same, the first is easier and should be used. This actually only works because Spring Boot detects `HandlerInterceptor` instances in the context and automatically registers them, this won't work in a plain Spring application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they are the same.

```java
registry.addInterceptor( new MyInterceptorOne()).addPathPatterns("/api/data/**");
```

Will internally use the [`MappedInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/MappedInterceptor.html) to register the `HandlerInterceptor` with the given URL pattern.

Now the registration of a `HandlerInterceptor` (which `MappedInterceptor` implements) as an `@Bean` works because Spring Boot (not plain Spring!) detects `HandlerInterceptor` beans in the context and automatically registers them for you. This won't work in a regular Spring application.

So the way to use is to use the `InterceptorRegistry` as that is the documented way and the `MappedInterceptor` is more of an internal support class.