# How to register an Interceptor in Spring Boot 3 and Spring Framework 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm building a backend using Spring Boot `3.1.0-SNAPSHOT`, which uses `Spring Framework 6x`.

**Interceptor:**

```java
@Slf4j
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info("preHandle");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        log.info("afterCompletion");
    }
}
```

In previous versions (Spring Boot 2), the way to add an Interceptor was:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor( new MyInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Now, the correct way to add this type of configuration class is:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    // Not working now
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor( new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/**");
    }

}
```

How to add an Interceptor now?

I have tried:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InterceptorRegistry interceptorRegistry() {
        InterceptorRegistry registry = new InterceptorRegistry();
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
        return registry;
    }

}
```

Not working...

A working example is by using `MappedInterceptor`:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor loginInter() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(null, new MyInterceptor());
    }

}
```

But according to other threads here, for example this one [MappedInterceptor Bean Vs WebMvcConfigurer addInterceptors. What is the correct (modern) way for adding Spring HandlerInterceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816821/mappedinterceptor-bean-vs-webmvcconfigurer-addinterceptors-what-is-the-correct), says that the correct way is by using `registry.addInterceptor()`. Sadly is not working for me this way.

How to correctly register an Interceptor now?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to still use the HandlerInterceptor with Spring Boot 3 replacing the javax class imports to jakarta:

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class AuthorizeInterceptorConfig implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
private AuthorizeController authorizeController;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response, Object handler) {
    return authorizeController.isValidUser(request.getHeader("X-Document-Id"));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.5/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf

We can still use `@Configuration` annotated class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` but without `@EnableWebMvc` annotation for this use case. So, the following is still valid.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor( new CustomInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Comment: After migrating our apps to spring boot 3.x version i'm getting this error. Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve nested path. appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

For jakarta it has an interface HandlerInterceptor with preHandle and postHandle methods. Here is a link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.java

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
   @Component
    public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(@Nullable HttpServletRequest request,
                                 @Nullable HttpServletResponse response, @Nullable Object object) {
            System.out.println("interceptor");
            try {
                System.out.println(new String(request.getInputStream().readAllBytes()));
               //printing body
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("interceptor error: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, Exception exception) {
        }
    }
```

step 2:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }
}
```